# how to Combinations dataframe Without using itertools in python?

Tags: python, combinations

The question is How to Combinations data frame Without using itertools packages?

I can compute 2 combinations in one row
there is a code that I write

```
def combinations(arr,r):
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    if r == 1:
      yield [arr[i]]
    else:
      for next in combinations(arr[i+1:],r-1):
        yield [arr[i]] + next

for combi in combinations([1,2,3,4,5],2):
  print(combi)
```

result is like

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
'
'
```

and I want to apply this kind of algorithm in the data frame

if the data frame like

df

```
  name location
1 a    [1,2,3]
2 b    [2,3,4]
3 c    [1,2,3,4]
'
'
```

**I don't know how to write the code to solve the below question**

1 and I need to find the 2 combinations in the data frame repeat in each row

such as

```
1 a [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
2 b [[2,3], [2,4], [3,4]]
3 c [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4], [3,4]]
'
'
```

2 and need to count each combination

such as

```
[1,2] 2 ##(mean that there are 2 combinations [1,2] in the data frame df)
[1,3] 2
[2,3] 3
'
'
```